# ¿Cómo puedo saber en qué fragmento me encuentro?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

En mi proyecto tengo mi ***Activity*** que lo uso como contenedor de ***4 fragmentos***, quiero saber si es posible obtener en que *fragmento* me encuentro (posición) mientras estoy en tiempo de ejecución, o si existe algun metodo que se este ejecutando constantemente para recibir la posición del *fragmento* en el que me encuentro.

Todo esto de debe a que quiero agregar una imagen dependiendo del *fragmento* que me muestre, es decir, indicar gráficamente en qué *fragmento* me encuentro.

Answer (score 0):

Para identificar en cual fragmento estás, podrías usar esto:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); //Desde Activity
Fragment fragmento = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
```

La variable `fragmento` contiene el fragmento que se encuentra actualmente en el contenedor

Y para obtener la cantidad de fragmentos que tengas en Stack :

```
int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
```

Answer (score -1):

Cuando cargues el fragmentos pasale por parametros la imagen a cargar o el nombre de la misma en forma de String. Adjunto ejemplo.

```
// Se crea el objeto fragmento. 
DetalleFragment frgDetalle = new DetalleFragment();

// Se establecen sus argumentos.
Bundle argumentos = new Bundle();
argumentos.putParcelable(ARG_IMAGE, image); // ARG_IMAGE = Constante Identificacion
frgDetalle.setArguments(argumentos);

// Se realiza la transacción.
FragmentTransaction transaccion = gestorFragmentos.beginTransaction();
transaccion.add(R.id.flContenedorDetalle, frgDetalle);
transaccion.commit();
```